# ¿Cómo puedo configurar visual studio code para abrir llaves con salto de Linea?

Tags: javascript, vscode

La cosa es así: yo creo una función cualquiera en javascript, como esta:

```
function example() {}
```

Pero cuando abro las llaves con la tecla <kbd>enter</kbd>, me queda de esta manera:

```
function example() {
}
```

Y lo que yo busco es que, al presionar <kbd>enter</kbd>, se abran de tal manera que quede así:

```
function example() {
  
}
```

Esta configuración siempre la he tenido por defecto, pero por alguna razón, de un día para otro dejo de funcionar correctamente.

¿Alguien sabe como recuperar esta opción?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! vs code no hace esas cosas por si solo, lo hacen los plugins... fijate si alguno cambio eso...

Comment: Que raro, probé en un vscode sin ningún plugins y no me ocurre eso... al dar enter ya estás creando un salto de línea **entre las llaves**... dejando una línea de código vacía y lista para escribir...

Comment: Confirmo que VS Code ya hace eso por defecto.